# Disable debugging of referenced project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Good day. I have 2 solutions on C# (Visual Studio 2008). First solution contains reference to built dll of second solution. When I debug first solution, appears code of second solution. It is no obvious and no useful for me. I want to debug solutions separately. How can I do this?

**Update:**

I deleted all PDB files, put DLL in new folder, updated the reference, but Visual Studio still find the source code. I can not hide it from VS! Help me please.

Comment: What do you mean code from the second solution appears?

Comment: I use debugging by steps, and when called dll functions, code files of other project are opened in the window of this project.

Comment: You mean solutions or projects? Not the same thing.

Comment: If you're stepping through I'm fairly certain there's no way to skip code when stepping through. However VS can 'step over' the next line of code using F10. If you do end up in another DLL you can hit Shift+F11 to step back and then F10 to step over the call.

Comment: Sorry, I mean solutions, of course. I do not understand, how VS finds path to source files of referenced dll.

Answer (score 1):

The only way VS can find the code for a random DLL is by using the debug information, which is stored in a PDB file in the same folder as the DLL.

So in solution 1, if you are referencing the DLL in the location where it was built by solution 2, then it probably has the PDB file in that same folder. And that's why VS can figure out where the source code is.

Try this:

1. Remove the reference to the DLL from solution 1
2. Copy the DLL from solution 2's bin\Debug folder to a brand new folder
3. In solution 1, add a reference to the DLL in this brand new folder
4. Also ensure the `<dllname>.PDB` does not exist anywhere below solution 2's directory structure.

Comment: The "bin\Debug" folder with DLL do not has the PDB file. There are only DLL file and XML with comments. PDB file is only in the "obj\Debug" folder of solution, but I never refer to it.